# How to document object-oriented MATLAB code?

Tags: matlab, documentation

I'm writing a sizable application using object-oriented MATLAB, and this has gotten me thinking about how to document the code. If this was C, I would use Doxygen. For Java, I'd use JavaDoc. Both have mostly agreed-upon standards for how class and method documentation should look and what it should contain.

But what about MATLAB code? The most I've seen in TMW's own classes is a short sentence or two at the top of the class, and I can't find any topics devoted to documenting sizable MATLAB applications.

So how do you document your MATLAB classes? Any particular style issues or additional tools?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I realize the question is stale, but for the benefit of Google: Matlab has a built-in feature for that. You write your comments in a certain style (a la JavaDoc) and they get picked up by the help and doc functions. It can be used to document classes, properties, and methods. It is surprisingly complete, yet a little finicky. The doc is here:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating-help.html

Answer (score 13):

I document my oo code the following way:

1. At the beginning of the file that contains 'classdef', I write a summary of what the class does, and typical usage. I also explain properties in detail and I add a 1-sentence description of each method.
2. After each property definition, I add one explanatory sentence about it (on the same line)
3. Each method is documented like a function, i.e. it has a H1-line, a synopsis, and an explanation of the input and output parameters.

When you call 'doc myClass', you will see (1) at the beginning, followed by the list of properties explained by the sentences you added in (2) and the list of methods that show the H1-line and the rest of the help (3) if you click on the link.

In addition, all my classes subclass a general superclass which implements (among others) the method 'help' that calls doc(class(obj)), which allows me to bring up the help from every instance of the class.

Example

```
%# MYCLASS is a sample class
%# All this text will show up at the top of the help if you call 'doc myClassName'
%#
%# myClass is an example for documentation. It implements the following properties and methods:
%# PROPERTIES
%#    myProp - empty sample property (some more explanation could follow here)
%#
%# METHODS
%#    myMethod - sample method that calls doc
%#

classdef myClass

properties
    myProp = []; %# empty sample property
end %# properties

methods

%%# MYMETHOD -- use %% so that you can easily navigate your class file
function myMethod(obj)
%#MYMETHOD calls up the help for the object
%#
%# SYNOPSIS myMethod(obj)
%# INPUT obj: the object
%# OUTPUT none
%#
   try
      doc(class(obj))
   catch
      help(class(obj))
   end
   end %#myMethod
end %#methods

end %#myClass
```

**Edit 1** If you want a nice html documentation, you can, in addition, use [m2html](http://www.artefact.tk/software/matlab/m2html/) to generate it for you. M2html will collect the help texts and it can even do dependency graphs.

**Edit 2** While m2html documents standard Matlab code nicely, it has no specific support for classes. This means that you get the methods as 'subfunctions' linked in the class, but you do not get as nice a summary as you'd get with Doxygen, or which you get with the built-in documentation browser.

Comment: can m2html generate documentation for the new classdef syntax in Matlab ? I cannot find any hint in the documentation.

Comment: @Jonas: Yeah m2html is cool, buit not the best for matlab classes. Further, you can't exclude certain directorys which you don't want to index and document! Is there any better way up to now to do it except doxygen? Thanks

Comment: What if you have more than one input and/or output?

Comment: then it's `myMethod(obj, other input)`

Answer (score 5):

Try [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/) with the [matlabdomain](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinxcontrib-matlabdomain) extension. Sphinx is a [Python](http://python.org) package that auto-documents code using [ReStructuredText (rst) markup](http://sphinx-doc.org/rest.html). The extension sphinxcontrib-matlabdomain allows auto-documentation of MATLAB code that uses rst markup recognized by Sphinx in its docstrings. Send bugs and suggestions to the [issue tracker on BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/bwanamarko/sphinx-contrib/issues).

For example, the following code in `my_project/my_fun.m`:

```
function [outputs] = my_fun(args)
% MY_FUN does really cool stuff
% [OUTPUTS] = MY_FUN(ARGS)
%
% :param args: Input arguments
% :type args: cell array
% :returns: outputs
% :raises: :exc:`my_project.InvalidInput`

code ...
end
```

would be documented in an rst file like this:

```
.. _my-project

My Project
==========
.. automodule:: my_project

    This folder contains all the functions and classes for my project.

My Function
-----------
.. autofunction:: my_fun
```

and would produce html (or pdf, latex, and many others) like what is shown on [this blog post](http://poquitopicante.blogspot.com/2013/04/sphinx-domains-for-matlab.html).

Answer (score 2):

There exists a Doxygen-Adapter for M-Files on FileExchange, see http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25925-using-doxygen-with-matlab.

Comment: the matlab adapter does not play nicely with windows in some cases; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701671/problem-with-input-filter-using-doxygen-1-6-3-on-windows-xp